# error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’

Tags: c, list, compiler-errors

I know this question has been asked numerous times previously, however I am racking my brain trying to figure out what is causing the error as I cannot identify where the usual missing semi-colon is.

```
<#include<stdio.h>
```

`#define MaxLenght 30`

`typedef int ElementType;`

`typedef int Position`

`typedef struct {`

`ElementType Elements[MaxLength];`

`Position Last;`

`} List L;`

`void MAKENULL_LIST(List *L){`

`L->Last=0;`

`}`

`Position First(List L) {`

`return 1;`

`}`

`Position EndList(List L) {`

`return L.Last+1;`

`}`

`ElementType Retrieve(Position P, List L) {`

`return L.Elements[P-1];`

`}`

`Position Next(Position P, List L) {`

`return P+1;`

`}`

`void printList(List L) {`

`Position P;`

`P = First(L);`

`while (P != EndList(L)) {`

`printf("%d ",Retrieve(P,L));`

`P = Next(P, L);`

`}`

`printf("\n");`

`}`

Error thrown by compiler:

`__tester__.c:26:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token } List *L;`

Comment: So which one is line `26` that the error references?

Comment: So I format your code and you reverse it? :-D

Answer (score 1):

You have several typos:

**1 Replace:**

```
#define MaxLenght 30
```

By

```
#define MaxLength 30
```

**2 Replace:**

```
typedef int Position
```

by

```
typedef int Position;
```

**3 Replace**:

```
} List L;
```

by

```
} List;
```

And voilà, it compiles.